# Quiver varieties associated to D_4

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, moduli-spaces, quivers

Let $Q=(I,\Omega)$ be the $D_4$ affine quiver. We choose as  dimension vector $(2,1,1,1,1)$ (where $2$ is on the central vertex). As this dimension vector is indivisible, we can choose a generic $\theta \in \mathbb{Z}^I$. We have the usual moment map $$\mu: R(\overline{Q},v) \to \mathbb{C}^I $$ from representations of the doubled quiver to $\mathbb{C}^I$.

We have different quiver varieties associated to these data (I do not know whether the notation is standard): $$\mathfrak{M}_{0,\theta}(v)=\mu^{-1}(0)//_{\theta}G(v)$$ and $$\mathfrak{M}_{\theta,\theta}(v)=\mu^{-1}(\theta)/G(v) $$

A computation shows that these varieties are actually of dimension  $2$: is there an explicit geometric presentation of such objects? If we choose $\theta$ in an appropriate way, we can think of $\mathfrak{M}_{0,\theta}(v),\mathfrak{M}_{\theta,\theta}(v)$ as certain moduli spaces of parabolic Higgs bundles/parabolic connections over trivial vector bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$.

I know that in this case we have a concrete description of the full moduli space (the so-called Hausel toy model). Also the character variety side is well understood as affine Del Pezzo surfaces. What about quiver side?

Comment: Aren't they just the simple surface singularity $\mathbb{C}^2/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma \subset \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is the dihedral group $D_4$, and its minimal resolution?

Comment: I think this should be true for $\mathfrak{M}_{0,\theta}(v)$. The other one should be diffeomorphic to the former,but not algebraically isomorphic (I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [Kronhimer's result](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-29/issue-3/The-construction-of-ALE-spaces-as-hyper-K%C3%A4hler-quotients/10.4310/jdg/1214443066.full) that $\mathfrak M_{\zeta_{\mathbb R},\zeta_{\mathbb C}}(\mathbf v)$ is $\mathbb C^2/\Gamma$ ($\zeta_{\mathbb R}=\zeta_{\mathbb C}=0$), its deformation ($\zeta_{\mathbb R}=0$), and the minimal resolution of the deformation (in general). Here $\Gamma$ is the binary dihedral group of type D4.

Comment: Perhaps just to extend on this a little bit, as the OP asked for "explicit geometric presentation": the singularity $Y=\mathfrak M_{0,0}(\mathbf v) =\mathbb C^2/\Gamma$ is affine, and well known to be a hypersurface in ${\mathbb A}^3$ given by an explicit equation; its deformation $Y_t =  \mathfrak M_{0,\zeta_{\mathbb C}}(\mathbf v)$ is still affine, and is given by a generic deformation of the equation of the hypersurface; the minimal resolution $X =  \mathfrak M_{\zeta_{\mathbb R},0}(\mathbf v)$ of $Y$ is not affine of course but is a composite of blowups of $Y=Y_0$...

Comment: ...finally indeed $X$ and $Y_t$ for $t\neq 0$ are diffeomorphic, in fact algebraic deformation equivalent, as they sit in the Grothendieck resolution family.